# How to concatenate strings within the same column based on a string pattern?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataframe which has a column that looks like this:

`data.frame(sample_name = c("Sample01", "g01", "g02", "g03", "Sample02", "g01", "g02", "Sample03", "g03", "g04", "g07"))`

I am trying to get it to look like this:

`data.frame(sample_name = c("Sample01_g01", "Sample01_g02", "Sample01_g03", "Sample02_g01", "Sample02_g02", "Sample03_g03", "Sample03_g04", "Sample03_g07"))`

The issue is that the sample number (e.g. g01, g02) is never in any numeric order and has different numbers of rows (the "g" prefix is always there!). So, I need this code to be flexible enough to handle the input without hardcoding anything.

I have attempted several for loops, pattern matching based on regex, and trying to assign grouping variables to do a group split. I know what I want it to do, but am having trouble converting it to code. This is the "english" (not code) version of what I'd like my code to do:

1. Identify the sample name based on regex (like this `"[A-Z][a-z]+[0-9]{2}"`)
2. Select from the row after the sample name until the row before the next sample name (e.g., all sample numbers)
3. Take the sample name from step 1 and concatenate with the identified sample numbers with an underscore and save to a new column

I have tried both Base R and Tidyverse. I generally prefer Tidyverse solutions but I'm desperate for anything! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(sample_prefix = ifelse(grepl("^Sample", sample_name), sample_name, NA)) %>%
  fill(sample_prefix) %>%
  mutate(sample_name = ifelse(!grepl("^Sample", sample_name), paste(sample_prefix, sample_name, sep = "_"), sample_name), .keep="unused") %>%
  filter(grepl("_", sample_name))
```

```
  sample_name
1 Sample01_g01
2 Sample01_g02
3 Sample01_g03
4 Sample02_g01
5 Sample02_g02
6 Sample03_g03
7 Sample03_g04
8 Sample03_g07
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `cumsum` + `ave` + `na.omit` like below

```
na.omit(
    transform(
        df,
        sample_name = ave(
            sample_name,
            cumsum(startsWith(sample_name, "Sample")),
            FUN = \(x) c(NA, paste0(x[1], "_", x[-1]))
        )
    )
)
```

which gives

```
    sample_name
2  Sample01_g01
3  Sample01_g02
4  Sample01_g03
6  Sample02_g01
7  Sample02_g02
9  Sample03_g03
10 Sample03_g04
11 Sample03_g07
```